# Add line break every 6 items in string

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a request at work to read a | delimited file and add a line break every 6 values and write it to a new file.  The data in the textfile looks like so (the actual values have been hidden):

```
product|11111111|name|2006-10-09|code1|code2 product|22222222|name|2006-10-09|code1|code2 product|33333333|name|2011-02-03|code1|code2
```

I'm using the following code to read the file and then output it to the new file:

```
// Read the txt file
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(FileUpload1.FileContent);
string formattedText = reader.ReadToEnd();
File.WriteAllText(Server.MapPath("~/filename.txt"), formattedText);
```

So in this example I would need to add a line break after the 6th value.  I'm relatively new to ASP.net so i'm sure i'm missing something fairly easy.

Comment: Okay, what's your question? All you've done is read the file and rewritten it exactly as it was. It doesn't appear that you've actually tried anything so far to achieve your goal. You should read up on reading files and string parsing in C#, there's plenty of stuff out there.

Comment: Please don't just ask us to solve the problem for you. Show us how _you_ tried to solve the problem yourself, then show us _exactly_ what the result was, and tell us why you feel it didn't work. See "[What Have You Tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com/)" for an excellent article that you _really need to read_.

Comment: Also, you say you need to add a line break after every 6th value, but the example input text you've shown already has a line break after every 6th value...

Comment: Read line by line, split them and write to a new file.

Comment: @L.B: To be fair that wasn't the case before somebody made an edit.

Comment: @MattBurland it was in the markdown, it just didn't have leading spaces to format it as such

Comment: @Matthew: Ah - fair enough. Then I really don't know what the OP actually has because it does appear to already have line breaks.

Comment: My mistake folks the data in the textfile was not displaying correctly. I edited it so it displays correctly

Comment: @tdev according to your text this should work `File.WriteAllText(filename,String.Join(Environment.NewLine, inputtext.Split()));` What is the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have just a single line with no breaks, you could do something like this:

```
var source = "product|11111111|name|2006-10-09|code1|code2|product|22222222|name|2006-10-09|code1|code2|product|33333333|name|2011-02-03|code1|code2";
var cells = source.Split('|');    // or use \t if it's really tabs

var lines = string.Join("\n", cells.Select((c,i) => new { c, i })
    .GroupBy(x => x.i / 6)
    .Select(x => string.Join("|", x.Select(y => y.c))));

Console.WriteLine(lines);
```

And then you can just write `lines` to a file as you had it before.

How this works:

- `Split` the original string on the delimiter to create an array of strings
- `Select` each of those cells into an anonymous object with it's value (`c`) and it's index (`i`)
- `GroupBy` those objects using the index divided by `6` (truncated because this is integer division - so items `0...5` end up in group `0`, items `6...11` end up in group `1` and items `12...17` end up in group `2`)
- For each group, `Select` the result of `string.Join`ing all the values together to give a single string per group
- Then `Join` all those strings together with `\n`.

See: https://dotnetfiddle.net/j5gWgC

Answer (score 0):

```
        using (var sr = new StreamReader(FileUpload1.FileContent))
        {
            string line;
            int count = 1;
            while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                File.WriteAllText(Server.MapPath(string.Format("~/filename.txt{0}", count), line);
                count ++;
            }
        }
```

This will save each line of your input as a file. The 'count' variable is used for creating distinct file names.

Comment: I don't believe this is what the OP is trying to do. Also, your `string.Format` is wrong. I assume you meant something like: `string.Format("~/filename{0}.txt", count)`

Comment: Yep, I neglected to add the placeholder, thanks for catching that. It seemed to me that this is was he was looking for. If not, he can disregard my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I like Matt Burland's LINQ answer, but if you feel like using a more direct  approach, you can always just use a `while` loop with a `StringBuilder`:

```
var str = "product|11111111|name|2006-10-09|code1|code2|product|22222222|name|2006-10-09|code1|code2|product|33333333|name|2011-02-03|code1|code2";
var delimiter = "|";
var sb = new StringBuilder();

// using a list for the List<T>.GetRange() method (see below)
var splitString = str.Split(new [] { delimiter }, StringSplitOptions.None).ToList(); 

var index = 0;
var numValues = 6;
while (index + numValues <= splitString.Count)
{
    sb.AppendLine(String.Join(delimiter, splitString.GetRange(index, numValues)));
    index += numValues;
}

Console.WriteLine(sb.ToString());

/* 
   Output:
     product|11111111|name|2006-10-09|code1|code2
     product|22222222|name|2006-10-09|code1|code2
     product|33333333|name|2011-02-03|code1|code2
*/
```

Again, this assumes that everything is in a single line.